# Date parsing with regular expressions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, datetime, parsing

I'm using match() in JavaScript to parse a dates from an RSS feed, I just can't get my head around the correct regular expression to find the date format.

Here's the date:

```
2009-05-11 16:59:20
```

And the regular expression so far:

```
if (dateToParse.match(/^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d/)) {
        dateTimeSeparator = " ";
        monthIndex = 0;
        dayIndex = 1;
        yearIndex = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/
```

This puts the date in the first to third groups, and the time in the forth to sixth groups.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this helps:

```
var digitpattern = /\d+/g,
    datetime = '2009-05-11 16:59:20',
    matches = datetime.match(digitpattern);

console.log ('year = ' + matches[0]);
console.log ('month = ' + matches[1]);
console.log ('day = ' + matches[2]);
console.log ('hour = ' + matches[3]);
console.log ('minutes = ' + matches[4]);
console.log ('seconds = ' + matches[5]);
```

Or, you might like to use something like [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than struggling with regex you should try [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). It is still in alpha but looks very promising with all its culture specific versions.

Comment: Cheers, just needed a quick hack for now but date.js looks really interesting.