# python regular expression date format mm/dd

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write an `RE` to find all `mm/dd` format

```
re = "((1[0-2])|(0?[0-9]))/(((1[0-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0-1])|(0?[0-9])))"
```

It finds all `mm/dd` format but also gives things like,

```
11/22 in 12311/22213
```

and

```
10/22 in 1110/22213
```

How do I exclude the cases above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<!\d)((1[0-2])|(0?[0-9]))/(((1[0-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0-1])|(0?[0-9])))(?!\d)
```

Of course it'll match stuff like 02/31, but that's a start. I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773823/why-doesnt-this-regular-expression-work-the-way-i-want-it/10774743#10774743) a regex that matches only valid dates.

Comment: The very edge case is 02/29, which is valid in some years, and not in others.

Comment: That one is impossible to catch by regex :-)